# Angular Slick slickGoTo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, slick.js

I'm using [angular-slick-carousel](https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel). The problem is Slick methods doesn't work, for example `slickGoTo()` .

This is my Controller as in the documentation :

```
$scope.slickConfig = {
   method: {}
};
```

And my view:

```
<slick infinite=true
        arrows=true
        speed=500
        slides-to-show=4
        slides-to-scroll=1
        as-nav-for=".slider-for"
        class="slider-nav"
        settings="slickConfig"
        >

    <a  href=""
        class="thumb col-xs-2"
        ng-repeat="photo in photos"
        ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickGoTo(2)"> // <<<< method doesn't work

        <img ng-src="{{photo.thumb}}" alt="">

    </a>

</slick>
```

**Maybe I'm using it WRONG?**

Answer (score 0):

I had this error: $scope.slickConfig.method.slickGoTo is not a function

My mistake: I was linking to [angular.slick](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick) instead of slick.carrousel... and, of course, slickConfig didn´t work.

Here is a plunker demo I found, it may help you:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hQWpQc4GFQKcV8BPtPLf?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]"><button ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickGoTo($index)">{{ i }} {{$index}}</button></div
<slick slides-to-show=1 slides-to-scroll=1 settings="slickConfig">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]"><h3>{{ i }}</h3>
    </div>
</slick>
```